# Client side error handling with Micronaut

Tags: rest, exception, error-handling, micronaut, error-code

I am using a Micronaut layer between a REST service and a consumer app.
|REST service|->|Micronaut client / controller|->|consumer app|.
When the REST service is returning an error, the controller should propagate the error code.
When the REST service is offline, the controller should return some kind of 500 error code.
However, right now it's returning an empty body with a 200 error code in both cases.

For the example here is my controller:

```java
@Controller("/api/v1") 
public class MyController {

private final ClientNetworkList clientNetworkList;

public MyController( 
    ClientNetworkList clientNetworkList,
){
    this.clientNetworkList = clientNetworkList;
}

    @Get(uri = "/networkList", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM)
    Flowable<NetworkListPackage> packagesNetworkList() { 
        return clientNetworkList.fetchPackages();
    }
}
```

And the client:

```java
@Client(FabricConfiguration.FABRIC_API_URL) 
public interface ClientNetworkList{
     @Get("/auth/networklist") 
    Flowable<NetworkListPackage> fetchPackages();   
}
```

How can I propagate or throw the correct body and error code?
How should I use the @Error annotation, should it be implemented in the controller or in a filter?

Comment: Can you show the source code for `ClientNetworkList`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. "ClientNetworkList" is actually the @client interface. It's now corrected in the question.

Comment: I am sure it is just a mistake in the code here, not the real code, but I think `this.ClientNetworkList` should be `this.clientNetworkList` and `return clientNetworkList.fetchPackages();` should be `return clientNetworkList.fetchPackages();`.

Comment: Yes, thank you for seeing this.

Answer (score 0):

Micronaut has a Circuit Breaker Support for such things.

I would recommend to use the @Fallback Annotation and throw an Exception which will produce the 500 Error Code. See [7.3.7 Client Fallback](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientFallback) in Micronaut Documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I couldn't find any other example than the one you provided. Does @Fallback has to be implemented in the client? To what error code is Fallback responding exactly?

Comment: You have to create a fallback Class which implements the client. As an Example see [Fallback Example Pet Store](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-examples/blob/master/petstore/offers/src/test/groovy/example/offers/TestPetClientFallback.groovy) in your case you will implement the method fetchPackages. In the fetchPackages method of your fallback you can simply throw an exception which will results in a 500er. If you are planning to customize the return check out the [ExceptionHandler](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/server/exceptions/ExceptionHandler.html)

Comment: `"Micronaut has a Circuit Breaker Support for such things."` - That is true but just for clarity, as discussed above you probably want `@Fallback`.   `@CircuitBreaker` is probably not relevant to the question.  This scenario isn't really about breaking the circuit.

Comment: `@CircuitBreaker` docs at https://docs.micronaut.io/2.1.1/guide/index.html#clientRetry, `@Fallback` docs at https://docs.micronaut.io/2.1.1/guide/index.html#clientFallback.